# How to perform PATCH operation in Firebase APi?

Tags: rest, firebase, curl, firebase-realtime-database

The firebase doc sys this is how it is supposed to be done:

curl -X PATCH -d '{"last":"Jones"}' \
 'https://[PROJECT_ID].firebaseio.com/users/jack/name/.json'

But I dont know how to convert this to a rest based request.

TO be clear I need to send a web request from javascript/java, hence I want to know what should be the body , and header and operation type for this request.

Can someone please help?

Comment: That is a REST based request.  It's from the REST API for Realtime Database.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/

Comment: @DougStevenson Yes, I know but I need to convert this to  web request

Comment: They're the same thing.  You'll need to edit your question to include more detail about what you're hoping to accomplish.

Comment: @DougStevenson Please find the updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the [documentation for curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html), you can figure out what that command line you showed is trying to tell you.

The HTTP method is: `PATCH`

The request body is: `{"last":"Jones"}`

The url is: `https://[PROJECT_ID].firebaseio.com/users/jack/name/.json`

Where PROJECT_ID is the name of your project.  That's all there is to it.

Comment: Thakns for the link I was not able to find the documentaiton

Answer (score 0):

You need teh following structure:

HTTP Request:

https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/*YOUPROJECT_ID*/databases/(default)/documents/users_admin/*DOCUMENT_ID*?**updateMask.fieldPaths=user_name&updateMask.fieldPaths=permisos.Administrador&updateMask.fieldPaths=user_email**

JSON Body (must be exactly the same structure and type as your database):

```
 {
  "fields": {
    "user_name": { "stringValue": "Test Actualización 2" },
    "permisos": {
      "mapValue": {
        "fields": {
          "Administrador": {
            "booleanValue": true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    
    "user_email": { "stringValue": "veviboj548@eyeremind.com" } 
  
  }
}
```